# Is it apporpriate to use two way ANOVA test if I have paired data linked to single individual?

Tags: anova, two-way

I am new in statistics. I wanted to do some statistical test to determine whether there is a difference between two samples and over the individuals.

So if I have data that looks like this:

```
Animal type   Numbers_method_1  Numbers_method_2

Tiger         28                 32
Lion          15                 19
Turtle        187                165
Giraffe       311                233  
Leopard       123                321
...
```

And I have 25 animal types like this. If possible I wanted to do two way comparison, between the methods, but also between the Animals. But since I have paired data linked to single animal, is it possible to use two-way ANOVA comparison, and if not, why? Do I have to link them into categories? Or in other words, is it impossible to do two way ANOVA with pairs linked only to a single case?

Also, this data is raw data, do I have to normalize it before performing such comparison between animals? ... because each animal is different of course.

Answer (score 1):

If your observations for a single animal type are correlated (as it is natural to assume, if they come from the same individual animal), you should not use ANOVA, but rather a [paired  comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paired_difference_test) if the matter of interest is the comparison between method 1 and method 2. If you were looking instead at differences between animals, than a [MANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_analysis_of_variance) one-way test seems adequate (you would have bivariate observations for each animal type).

Independence of observations is a requirement in standard ANOVA, in order for the count of degrees of freedom to be correct.

Comment: that was useful. Why two way ANOVA cannot be used in the cases where there are no cathegories but single individual type and paired data? Also, if I use paired comparison, do I need to normalize my raw data? Because I will be comparing samples from different animals so I guess raw data wouldnt be super helpful?

Comment: In standard ANOVA, the denominator of the test statistics is something like $\sum_{ij}(y_{ij} -  y_{i.})^2/(IJ-I)$ (one way ANOVA; but the idea extends to others too). If observations are independent, this sum of squares suitably scaled is $\chi^2$-distributed with $IJ-I$ defgrees of freedom. If independence fails, this is no longer true, and the null distributions of the test statistics no longer are correct.

Comment: I don't know how you plan to normalize. I guess what you need for a paired comparisons test is that the variance of the $(y_{i1} - y_{i2})$  (difference of measures for animal $i$) is constant across $i$, or nearly.

Comment: I see. I have found one paper with similar data and it says:  " The distribution of the method difference in  values for each animal was compared with the normal distribution using the Shapiro-Wilk test. If the difference was distributed normally at the confidence level of 95%, the dependent t-test for paired samples was performed to determine whether or not the differences between the two samples were statistically significant at this confidence level. Otherwise, the Wilcoxon signed-rank test was used"

Comment: So as I understand I can use Sharipo-Wilk test to compare the normal distribution of my sample? Then if normally distributed I can use dependent t-test on normal data, and if not normally distributed I have to use Wilcoxon-signed ranked test, is that correct?

Comment: In order to test for normality you assume all observations come from a single distribution (otherwise, which normal you are testing proximity to?) So commonality of variances appear to me first and foremost.